# What makes a "good" performance question on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've just achieved the ability to review close/reopen votes, and am trying to take this responsibility seriously. I was presented with the following question, and recommended that it be closed as too broad. Everything I've seen suggests that "here is my working code - please make it better" questions are not on topic at SO, and should be closed. But this was a test, and I apparently failed. The review queue admonished me for voting to close, saying there's nothing wrong with the question. That said, I really don't understand what I should have done differently in reviewing this answer!

[Inverting an Order-Preserving Minimal Perfect Hash Function in Better than O(K*lg N) Running Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646216/inverting-an-order-preserving-minimal-perfect-hash-function-in-better-than-okl)

Quick background on the question is that it presents a (perfectly fine) implementation of a specific algorithm, then states that it doesn't run fast enough, and asks for help improving the theoretical or implementation efficiency.

So my question is, what are there characteristics of *good* "please improve my code" questions that I should look for? Or is this audit question a bad one?

These related questions suggest the topic is murky at best:

- [Is asking about the performance of a library a valid SO question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290779/is-asking-about-the-performance-of-a-library-a-valid-so-question)
- [Are questions about improving performance on topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136451/are-questions-about-improving-performance-on-topic-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: "*Everything I've seen suggests that "here is my working code - please make it better" questions are not on topic at SO*" they are, though. They might *also* be on-topic for Code Review but that doesn't make them off-topic for SO. Remember that SO is about specific problems, while CR is for more general advice on the code. "My code needs to run faster" is specific. Especially when supplied with all the information the question you linked has - background to the question, goal, explanation, specific criteria to improve upon.

Comment: Interesting - so if the goals are well specified enough to make them "a specific programming problem" then it's a valid question... thanks!

Comment: I don't know what rules currently say, but if they don't allow questions like that, I'm all for fixing them!

Comment: On the point of Code Review there is a [rather comprehensive answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/249511) on their meta that says, "Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that "it belongs on Code Review". Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason, and sloppy reasoning perpetuates inappropriate referrals. Not all questions about analyzing code are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and not all code review requests are on-topic on Code Review. Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based."

Comment: @HenryEcker *"Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based"* - yes - this is exactly the type of thing I've seen referenced plenty on SO. I think what I didn't understand (and still would love some guidance on) is what makes an opinion-based "please improve this" question a good one? Is it specific criterias for success? Really detailed question specification? Or does it just have to meet some interestingness bar?

Comment: There is no (or, at least, there should not be) an "interestingness bar" for closure. Performance questions are on topic if they include a specific area of focus for improvement, can be answered with facts/citations (like specific timings/memory analysis), and such an answer would not be an unreasonable length (e.g. you could write an entire book on the topic). Full transparency: I don't ask or answer many performance questions someone with more experience with those types of questions would be better able to point to specific questions which do this well.

Comment: Since "performance" and "time complexity" are two different yardsticks, I think it's worth mentioning that Improving _time complexity_ (as is the case here) tends to be much more of an actionable, measureable request than improving _performance_, which is often a nebulous concept. Performance on which machine, under which workload, measured how? I've always thought [Eric Lippert's "Which is Faster?"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is a good summary of a lot of the ambiguities that tend to appear in "efficiency"/performance questions.

Comment: What did you think was wrong with that question? I see nothing wrong with it, certainly nothing that would match with one of our close reasons.

Comment: Side point: SQL performance questions *must* include table and index definitions, and execution plans, otherwise they are not answerable and should be closed. I suppose the same could be said of any performance question where it's not easy to actually rig up tests.

Comment: I tend to close as “needs more focus” questions that are just code with the question “fix this for me” or “make it faster”. Because those questions are not only lazy, but also useless to the purpose of Stack Overflow. But this question is definitely not a code dump, the author put a lot of effort and thought into it, and I could see how someone else might have a similar problem, and would find that post useful.

Comment: Some on-topic performance questions: [sort by votes in the `[performance]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance?tab=Votes), some of them are still considered on-topic today, even old ones like SO's highest voted Q&A about branch prediction: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809).  Also [Why are elementwise additions much faster in separate loops than in a combined loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8547778) (4k aliasing effects on Intel)

Comment: Although there are plenty of highly-voted Q&As of dubious value, so not all old questions are signs of what we want to see in terms of new questions.  It seems you're more asking about [tag:optimization] questions, about speeding up code, rather than [tag:performance] about explaining possibly-surprising performance effects.  Many [simd] questions are like that, with scalar code and asking how to vectorize, although we tend to be generous about questions without an attempt at manual vectorization like [How to vectorise int8 multiplcation in C (AVX2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69846842).

Comment: (Generous vs. implementing simple logic at all, like for homework questions.  It's expected that everyone can at least program, and it's also expected that we won't have to explain every single detail of using SIMD intrinsics, i.e. it's assumed that the asker knows about SIMD basics like load and store intrinsics, just hasn't come up with a way to use them for their specific problem, even if they don't show an attempt, if the problem is non-trivial.)

Comment: In my opinion, code review questions *are* programming questions and the only reason, they are considered off-topic on Stackoverflow is that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ exists as a distinct SE site (which doesn’t make a good reason). If that site didn’t exist and there was just a `[code-review]` tag on Stackoverflow, nobody would ever discuss whether a particular question is off-topic because it belongs to Codereview.SE. I’ve seen questions which were well on-topic because the OP provided plenty of information, but turned code-review because the issue was something else… That’s life.

Comment: @Holger As you yourself admitted, the existence of a Code Review site cannot make a question off-topic for SO. When there is overlap in scope between two sites, it is the asker's choice on which site they want to ask their question. If they chose SO, and the question is on-topic here, then it should not be migrated anywhere else. Ever. Full stop. As far as the existence of Code Review, it is for *open-ended* code reviews where the person is looking for any/all types of feedback on their code. That'd be too broad for an SO question. Specific questions about small snippets of code are OK here.

Comment: @CodyGray then, we fully agree, but I’m afraid, a lot of users on this site didn’t understand that. Is there a canonical document we can redirect such close voters?

Comment: @Holger [This](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) is the canonical reference on not migrating questions away unless you've already determined they are off-topic for the site on which they're asked. In particular: *"Be a bit jealous of your site – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else."* The author is Josh Heyer, also known as Shog9. As for the purpose of Code Review, their Meta site has a lot of FAQs on the purpose of their site and how it is different from SO.

Comment: If you need a reference for specific questions about small snippets of code being OK on Stack Overflow, then look no further than our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As long as the question is reasonably focused, is about programming, and is sufficiently clear, then it's on-topic here. That would include a question about how to improve the readability of a specific section of code, or, equally, a question about how to optimize the performance of a specific bit of code.

Comment: That question provides 2 strategies for improvement. So it shows, that author not just asks, but also proposes ways of the solution. So that is perfectly fine question.

Comment: @CodyGray while the Help Center allows the conclusion that such questions are on-topic, it seems it was not sufficient to convince everyone. Shog9’s article is helpful. Further, I’ll bookmark your comment saying it explicitly, for future reference ;^)

Comment: @CodyGray I am not an active person on SO, but [for facing to a similar issue and not getting satisfied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422452/13394817) want to ask: Why not code_review be just a tag, because many professional are active just on SO (e.g., user:12939557, for Numba) and the question could be answerable (not much work) by them, and closers (reviewers) just score that to move it to CR automatically after a time (e.g., a week);

Comment: By which, the authors may get better answers and more probable free professionals will contribute in that. Besides, differences in opinions will not be arised for being on-topic or off-topic, open-ended or not, … , for performance tag. I am really much more agree by [@Holger comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger), and it will make it much easier for the authors (particularly newbies).

Comment: This isn’t really a good spot for a “should we merge all cs/code/tech sites on stack exchange into stack overflow” debate. This site has had strict on topic guidance which excludes code review form the beginning, so you’re unlikely to get much traction with this idea. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312863/are-code-review-questions-off-topic

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the question listed - it is objectively a good question:

- it lists **a specific goal**
- it provides **example code that does not satisfy the goal** (showing that the asker has attempted to solve the problem themselves)
- it discusses **considerations around the provided code with regards to the desired goal** (showing that the asker understands the problem space)

About the only sin the question commits is being overly verbose, but that is only a bad thing if you are one of the tl;dr crowd with a 5-second attention span, in which case you aren't wanted here anyway.

At the end of the day, this question is the exact opposite of a homework/help vampire gimme-teh-codez question. It is well-researched, thoughtful, exemplar of a question. If all questions on SO were as "bad" as this one, the site would be an incredible place like it was back in 2011.

Answer (score 20):

To answer your title: that it has a very specific metric to improve. The thing is that many questions aren't about that, but "make this faster". So, your example "here is my working code - please make it better" doesn't avoid the "every answer is equally valid" from [don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (note, this is explicitly allowed in Code Review as long as the code is working and you explain what it does). Every answerer would have a definition that would make the code "better" and we wouldn't be able to identify a wrong answer.

The problem with the specific question you point to is that the asker seems to go on a red herring about their code not matching their expected (and probably not possible) time complexity metrics. The asker is thinking that the invert of the perfect hash function has a O(n) solution (someone showed it does). Basically, OP doesn't know or hasn't figured out the algorithmic solution that fulfills their requirements. The code there is merely a illustration, as you can see, the answerer didn't even propose an answer in C++.

TL;dr this question isn't a "make my code better", but "find me the O(n) algo".

Answer (score 12):

I don't think this question has a single answer (-; but that seems to be OK on meta.

In my experience the main things that make performance questions unacceptable are:

- absence of metrics (how fast is it, how fast does it need to be) including the method used for measurement
- absence of a repro (unclear exactly what code we're trying to measure or improve)
- insufficient information about the technology stack in use (e.g. for XSLT problems, failure to state which XSLT processor is being used)
- questions of the form "is A faster than B" where there has been no attempt to make any measurements (and where there is no attempt to demonstrate that it actually matters to the bottom line)

Most questions that don't fall into one of these holes would, I imagine, be worth attempting to answer.

Comment: Regarding "is A faster than B", Eric Lippert has a great blog post about that: [Which is faster?](//ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). He covers the same points: *"You can ... discover which ... is faster by running both yourself and measuring them"* and *"The question presupposes that there actually is a performance problem to be solved."* Then goes on: *"Use a profiler ..."*; *"If neither [] is fast enough for your purposes then knowing which is faster is irrelevant."*; *"optimizing for one [kind of speed] can deoptimize for another."*

Answer (score 7):

SO is **one concern per question,** and **with an objective criterion for an answer.** This is needed to make questions reusable for future readers: if there are multiple concerns, it's far less likely that a reader will have this exact combination; if the criterion is subjective, you can't really answer the question -- at all and fully -- because you don't know what would qualify and what qualifies for one person woudn't for another, and because an infinite number of answers can be equally valid.

In this case, there is one concern: they need an algorithm that is faster than a specific Big O. And  there's an objective criterion.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, some 95% of the questions on Stack Overflow regarding poor performance are caused by incorrect benchmarking. Benchmarking is not trivial - in most systems it is a more complex topic than actually writing efficient code for that system. And then there's an embarrassingly high amount of questions asking about performance when the OP has not even enabled compiler optimizations.

Therefore, a good performance question first of all needs to state:

- Target system. That is, instruction set ([ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)) and OS.
- Compiler and compiler options used.
- How the benchmarking was performed.
- Benchmarking results - why they are considered poor and what the OP is hoping for instead.

The next mistake to avoid is mixing up algorithm theory with actual program performance. "Big O" notation is a way to measure *the number of iterations* in an algorithm. This does often not correspond to the number of actual *comparisons*, making it a somewhat irrelevant metric for real-world performance.

On a modern high-end computer with instruction cache, branch prediction and pipelining, iterations are cheap, but comparisons are expensive. Therefore, "Big O" may or may not be relevant. For example, searching through the whole of a (sorted) array of data with a brute force linear search might be much faster than searching through the same data with binary search. A linear search may have fewer comparisons, leading to fewer branches and may also allow the computer to utilize data cache more efficiently than an O(log n) binary search that jumps around and touches various parts of the data, with little or no correspondence to actual cache lines. For each iteration in a binary search, there are likely multiple comparisons.

Also, binary search often involves division which may be inefficient - "Big O" knows nothing about such things. The whole "Big O" algorithm theory pre-dates cache memories by some decades and has no connection to the underlying machine code in general. (Unless one claims that "Big O" is the number of comparisons, then it's another story.)

The linked C++ question is a perfect example of someone mixing up algorithm theory with real-world performance. It's very branch-intensive code. Furthermore, the C++ type-generic programming is likely going to result in wildly different code depending on what type that is used. The question says that the template type might be a [std::vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)#Vector), so this code sits on multiple abstraction layers above the actual machine code. In which case the focus should first of all be: do these abstraction layers make sense for the problem this code is supposed to solve, or are there more efficient ones? Is there hidden bloat caused by type-generic programming? And so on - it's kind of an "XY question".

It is a decent question if it is asking about algorithm theory, but it is a bad question in case it is asking about real-world performance of executed C++ code.

Comment: Re: the many questions with improper benchmarking methodology, [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) may be a helpful canonical duplicate for many of the pitfalls that benchmark frameworks help to avoid, if used properly.  (Especially CPU frequency, cache, page-fault warm-up issues, and compiler optimization.)

Answer (score 4):

This may be somewhat beside the point, or maybe just a bit broader, but many questions asks for the "most efficient" way of doing a certain thing. This is much more vague than many people think.

First, the most common interpretation of this is "lowest execution time". But even this is very vague. Because there are many factors that come into play. First, we have the target computer. Is it a single core cpu? How fast is the memory? What operating system? There are TONS of things that counts here. So "the fastest" is not a good question.

And we also have what data we're operating on. Some algorithms may be very fast on huge data, but slow on small data. At least relatively speaking. For instance, it's common that sorting algorithms are switching from quick sort to bubble sort for short lists. And the relation between data size and cache can also play a big part. Some algorithms gets a huge performance drop after a certain size because they are not cache friendly.

Furthermore, it's not only the data size that matters. Lists that are almost sorted are very easy to fix for some algorithms. Very often, the real data is far from random. This also affects performance.

So far we have three very different things that will affect performance a lot. The target machine, the size of the data, and the data itself. So it's quite obvious that "most efficient" is a very vague question.

But there's more. Execution time is not the only way of measuring efficiency. Let's have a look at networks. Games usually required very low latency for good gameplay. In other scenarios, the throughput is much more important.

And there's even more. Efficiency can be measured in memory usage. Some algorithms are very quick but at the cost of using tremendous amount of memory. Low memory usage is a very reasonable way of measuring efficiency.

Most performance questions gets closed because they are not precise enough. Not because performance questions are off topic per se.