# Would the following review audit be seen as unsuitable?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

The following [review queue audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/34156907) got me a review suspension.

This question is about performance as

> The problem is that it takes too long

and

> Most efficient way to continuously find the median

However, finding the most efficient way to solve something may be subjective. We don't have the hardware configuration (which would be the only way to make it objective). See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419271/why-are-questions-about-performance-discouraged).

Should this question be suitable for Stack Overflow?

Comment: not every "efficiency" question relies on the hardware being the same or known for an objective answer (or multiple) to exist.

Comment: @KevinB That was the point of the question. I want to know the in-between and how I can learn from it. I think I should've written this differently.

Answer (score 9):

I mean, what *else* could the OP have possibly said in their question?

They provided for us:

- Inputs
- Step-by-step data flow
- Expected outputs
- Their code which *does work* but is a little slow

It's pretty safe to assume that they're not running it on their own hardware, if they're receiving feedback that their program is timing out on a few test cases.

What the OP is looking for is someone to troubleshoot the performance of the code, given the known good inputs and known good outputs.

In the context of the review queues, I don't see how an edit could improve this post.  All the information that a subject matter expert needs to be able to solve this problem is present.

Comment: The code in the question looks to be an order of magnitude of O(n^2 * log n ^ 2) which is clearly way above the O(n log n) for finding median (or anything reasonable for a competition task)... Completely agree that it's hard to add something other information to the post.

Comment: Not what they could have *said* but what they could have removed. When I read "**Most efficient way**" I think of it as an efficiency question. Those questions are subjective, right? And it doesn't give specs at all (even if it's not needed, I don't know the subject very well at all). Maybe I should have skipped. Either way, I couldn't find a canonical answer under meta that this question falls under.

Answer (score 7):

> However, finding the most efficient way to solve something may be subjective.

You severely oversimplified the question.  The author clearly defined the problem, indicated that their current solution was only passing 6/10 of their test cases, and was seeking help to pass all 10 test cases. The question received 4 answers which explained methods to pass all 10 test cases.

> We don't have the hardware configuration (which would be the only way to make it objective).

You didn't need to know their hardware configuration to recommend a solution to their problem.  Had you reviewed the answers the question received you would have determined it was easily answered and did NOT require the author to edit it.

Furthermore, if you thought the question would lead to subjective answers, you should have instead voted to closed the question. **I only say that, because if the question was seeking an opinion, then it should have been closed until it was modified so it no longer sought our opinion.**

Since this was a review audit, you failed because you choose the wrong review option for the Triage queue.

> Should this question be suitable for Stack Overflow?

Yes;  Questions, seeking clearly defined solutions which provide a specific problem and that contain a MRE, should be allowed on Stack Overflow.

> The following review queue audit got me a review suspension.

To be reviewed suspended you must have either failed numerous audits recently, or because you choose the wrong option in a highly visible queue like Triage, a moderator manually suspended you because of your decision to choose the wrong option. **Without performing a deep analysis on your review queue history, there is a good chance, the failed audit is only partially the reason you were temporally suspended from future reviews.**

Users are not reviewed suspended because of one recent incorrect review queue decision, or if they are, is because the decision was so obviously the incorrect option a moderator thought the only way to point out their incorrect mistake was to issue a review suspension.

BLUF: "Needs author edit" in the context of the Triage review queue, means that the only way for the question to be of acceptable quality, is for the author of the question to edit it. **A well received question, with 4 well received answers, does NOT match that description.**

Comment: *Users are not reviewed suspended because of one recent incorrect review queue decision* I knew that. My last failed review is a month ago (until today). But I just want to know *why* because this question is about performance right? Based on the answers to the linked meta question I want to know where this falls.

Comment: @BlueRobin - No; The question is about the fact their code failed 6/10 test cases.  A single failed audit a month ago isn’t enough to get you review banned. So that tells me, a moderator decided, your decision to choose the incorrect option was severe enough to make you slow down your review process in the future. Yes; I do recognize that the accepted answer does talk about the performance cost of the authors code. One could easily remove the statements about performing and the question could still be answered

Comment: *One could easily remove the statements about performing and the question could still be answered* shouldn't there still be a clarity edit? Also, I remember the suspension being instant.

Comment: @BlueRobin - The number of failed audits is taken into consideration. So if the last failed audit was a month ago, that could be based on your history of with fail audits, be a deciding factor in the system preventing you from performing additional reviews.  What exactly is your point about the clarify edit? You indicated the question could ONLY be improved by the author and that simply was NOT the case.

Answer (score -4):

### Just because a truth isn't universal doesn't make it subjective

Program speed, in the sense of how much time is taken to perform a given task, is about as objective as it gets. Time is a scalar, numeric quantity.

Yes, which program will perform a task faster might theoretically depend on the input, or on hardware details. **However**:

- The **common case** for optimization problems is that the algorithm is a total loser, in the big-O sense. For sufficiently large N, anything that implements a better big-O will be faster - *by definition*. (The practical *usually* lines up quite well with the theoretical, here, too.)
- "Most efficient" doesn't have to mean "please take every possible opportunity to micro-optimize this". That's a bad-faith interpretation that needlessly broadens the question - if there are multiple lines of code, each might offer a micro-optimization that is the answer to a separate implied question. It's nice for answerers to offer this kind of information (and better yet, to include reference links for canonicals about the kinds of micro-optimization being applied), but it's **by no means understood to be expected or required**.
- If, for some reason, there is a natural "efficient" way to solve the problem that inherently involves some tradeoff (for example speed vs. memory, or the best value for some configuration parameter will depend on hardware details), then **that is not subjective** either. A good answer should, and clearly *can*, just *explain how to make the decision*.

### Even if this were a problem, it could easily be fixed in editing

Come on. We shouldn't be closing questions that are almost suitable and would become suitable with a minor change of phrasing, because of some kind of "authorial intent" quibble. Here I thought I was gaining a reputation as the strongest advocate on Meta for closing more questions, and even I think that's ridiculous. **The purported intent to ask a sub-par question, when a better version is obvious, is not worth preserving.**

Comment: I'm sorry, I must've missed it.  What was the "minor change of phrasing" you were thinking that this needed?  I'll clarify that the OP found this in the review queues of all places, as an audit, absent context, comments or other answers.

Comment: **Hypothetically**, if we supposed that "Most efficient" needed to become "An efficient" or something. I don't think it does, but I'm saying that this **still** wouldn't be a reason to vote "needs author edit". (I thought that the phrasing "Even if this were a problem" clearly conveyed "I don't think this is a problem".)

Comment: Okay, I **genuinely** don't understand what people are objecting to here. I **explicitly** marked the potential "minor change of phrasing" as **not needed** via my section header, and no other objection has been raised. I don't think I'm saying anything else controversial, and I think I'm broadly in agreement with Makoto. So why -3?