# Is this question really a good close votes audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

In this post [GCS Connector Hadoop3 hadoop3-2.2.8 - Slow read, exists, rename and create operations](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33147234), the main question is

> Is there any guidelines on parameter configurations to improve the above operations time?

To me, it is clearly asking for an opinion and is too wide. So, I failed the audit.  How is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: If one changes the question slightly to "Are there any parameter configurations to improve the above operations time?" does that make it better? That's what I think OP is asking, and that doesn't seem opinion based to me. I'd leave the part of whether it is focused or not to the SMEs.

Comment: Does that not belong in Code Review then?

Comment: This question might be a good read to answer that: [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so)

Comment: The quote seems to be doing a disfavour to the question. The question has a detailed writeup of the performance results, considerations and dependencies that should allow for an *objective* answer to the observed performance issue.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - The issue isnt whether the question is good. Its whether its a good csndidate for audit. I  think that many reviewers probably fail it. But I  am not privy to that information.  What are the stats for it ?

Comment: @RohitGupta I'm not following. Whether the question is good (with respect to close worthyness) seems to be the only important criteria. If there is an actually good question that many reviewers fail to identify as such, that is a good audit in my book.

Comment: Allow me to be honest for a moment. You make a flat statement "To me, it is clearly asking for an opinion and is too wide". Okay. Fine. But that does not absolve you from the responsibility of explaining yourself why you believe that, because *you might be wrong*. The hole you left in your meta post is the context needed to understand where you are coming from.

Comment: @RohitGupta "_many reviewers probably fail it_" it has been used as an audit thrice till now it seems where 1 user passed and 2 (including you) failed. This information is viewable from the [post's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74112537/timeline)

Comment: @Gimby - It seems to me that you are taking this as an attack on the question.  This isn't about the validity of the Question.  The issue, and is only my opinion, is that I think it may not be a good candidate for audits.  I still maintain that it's a tad ambiguous.  **"Is there any guidelines"** - do you not regard this as asking for an opinion ?  **"improve the above operations"** - do you not regard this as belonging in Code Review.  We all have different biases and slants, and I think it would be perfectly valid for me to share something.  But that makes me fail the audit.

Comment: I think this is an excellent candidate for an audit. The question boils down to "I've updated this connector from version x to version y and I saw an unexpected performance decrease, how do I alleviate this?" with all the relevant details for reproduction afaict. That is a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow, especially since it's a performance abnormality (was fast, is slow) instead of a blanket "my code is slow pls help", and as a reviewer you should've recognized that. Not the end of the world, but a good reminder that a blank "open ended performance question -> close" is wrong