# Why was my question about improving the performance of a code closed as lacking focus?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

Yesterday I posted [What is the best way / algorithm to make this sequential sorting code more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971712) (deleted) and it was closed with [needs to be more focused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417486/13394817) mark (It had a mistake and was not clear enough). I posted a new question [Is it possible to improve the performance of this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977526) but with several edits based on advises in [Why was my question about improving the performance of sequential sorting code in NumPy closed as lacking focus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422441) : shortening the code, explaining the goal again in an understandable way, more focused and removed suspicious parts relating to probable multiple answers, but it closed again. The new post was:

> Title: **Is it possible to improve the performance of this code**
>
> I have a 2D array *mod_arr* with shape (`m*n`) that contains integers/indices and need to be modified (values in each row will be swapped in that row) based on some comparisons (sorting schemes) on values in the 3rd dimension (`r`) of a 3D NumPy array with shape (`m*n*r`) *nav_org*; In the 3D array the inner 2D arrays are considered independent of each other in comparisons. Rows will be swapped in each of these inner 2D arrays based on some sequential comparisons for the columns’ values. So, I first modify the 3D array and then based on the changes that were applied on this array, I modify the 2D integer array. So, in each of the inner 2D arrays:
>
> 1. Sorting based on the 4th column in reverse order
> 2. Sorting the first 7 rows based on the 2nd column in reverse order (Such separations are for comparing independently i.e., independent
>    from values in the rest 3 rows, where nums_div = 10 --> comparison
>    will be among just these 7 rows)
> 3. Sorting the rest 3 rows based on the 1st column

```
CODES
```

> As this code will be called many times in my simulation, it will be
> better if could be more performant (now, for  `nums=1000000`,
> `params=4`, `nums_div=10`, it takes around 0.8 S, where 11 hours will
> be consumed by that if we call **just the body that shown on the
> code** 50000 times by a system with corei5 CPU and memory 16 Gb).   I
> am seeking for any other faster intelligent way if possible, without
> Cython, with NumPy or Numba, to get **res** (`np.int64`), where `nav`
> and comparations must be based on at least `np.float64` (or more
> precise if it could, not the main goal; any recommendation will be
> appreciated in this regard).
> **Notes:**
>
> - For *params* and *nums_div*, the mentioned values (3 and 7 respectively) are almost used, so consider them instead the minimum
>   values for benchmarks.
> - The proposed code, preferably, be applicable on the both Python versions 2 and 3; Python 3 is the first priority.
> - Be careful about choosing `nums` and `nums_div` which must satisfy `nums % nums_div = 0` for data creation in the prepared example.

I couldn't figure out the main issue with that to improve that or post
a new question in the true manner.

Please help further to clarify the issues with my post.

Comment: Link text should be help people to understand what will they found when following the link. When the links points to SO questions IMHO the best is to keep the question title.

Comment: When a question is closed, it's a bad practice to delete the question and post an improved version as a new question, instead, edit the closed question and wait for it be reopened. If you repeat the bad practice you might got a question post ban.

Comment: @Rubén I didn't know that. I just did what the warning said *You can edit the question or **post a new one**.* I will consider it. I will undelete the ex SO post if needed.

Comment: Don't forget that [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) exists for code that is already correct but could use ideas for improvement, including performance gains.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Right, I've little experience with that but it must be said (as I wrote in my SO question' comments):  I really follow some experts on SO who are very professional at performance (as *user:12939557*), and you can see some of their answers on my ex much more complicated questions, who are not active on Code Review, who I believe on them and I think their answers on my asked topics will probably be the best. I will try that, but hope SO reopen my question, because I really did/do not think that my question was so inappropriate to be closed there. tnx.

Comment: @Ali_Sh no? With a title that literally begins with the words "What is the best way"? The bullets were already in the air at that point.

Comment: @Gimby , I've changed the title, hope it help.

Comment: It seems the issues in my post is under the magnifying glass. I am editing my post for 2 days by the feedbacks that I get on this forum and SO, but again I get negative feedbacks. I doubted that if my edited post is seen or not. And I don't know what else should I do?

Comment: Ultimately, you have stumbled upon a kind of question which does not make a great fit for the Stack Exchange network. The site itself could perhaps do a better job at communicating this. It is also true that the advice on editing or posting a new question [is indeed bad and has been strongly contested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552). Should I be the one with the problem at hand, I would research for one feasible approach to optimizing the heavy load of the program (for example, use Numba) and eventually ask more specifically about it.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger tnx for the comment, I don't know what to say. Do you mean my question on SO was not appropriate for the site? So, why there are related tags e.g. *performance*, *optimization* and … there with lots of posts. I really, didn't understand exactly the purpose of *The site itself could perhaps do a better job at communicating this*. I have improved the code a lot if you see my edits, I used just NumPy in the new answer and using other libraries like Numba needs to be written professionally with in-depth knowledge about hardware and algorithms to propose based on the case.

Comment: Your closed question was deleted by you. Why? **Asking a question then deleting it (instead of editing it) is toxic behavior** I can’t review it and provide feedback because you deleted it.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't understand. Which question are you talking about? This question is closed, but not deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977526/is-it-possible-to-improve-the-performance-of-this-code  and I delete my ex question that was misunderstanding the community warning, see: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404097/philipxy,

Comment: @SecurityHound this *This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.* was confusing and I opened a new question based on misunderstanding. But I want to delete the new one and move the changes into the ex question because there is an answer there and I think it is better to do this, But, now, I don't know doing it or not, before reopening.

Comment: I am not a Numpy SME but your question could potentially also be closed as "Needs details or clarity", you seem to be solving a specific problem but are just giving an algorithm you've come up with to solve it. Optimizing might involve actually coming up with a separate algorithm (And that needs information on the actual problem). Although I believe that if you give those details your question would truly lack focus and be too specific. In general as others have mentioned your question might just not be a great fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat tnx for your comment. It was not my first post with performance tag, and I was tracing other question with this tag, also with Python, Numba, NumPy. I really disagree with *not a good fit*, so why other questions (by others and me) were not closed or … before, which were much more complicated. IDK, I think this is, perhaps, because users want direct this type of questions to code review (where the maximum posts by Numba is lower than 30 posts, now). I have edited the post extremely based on the notes get from people here, and on the post; but it is again closed; next comment

Comment: "_why other questions (by others and me) were not closed_" can you give examples of these? Note that not all performance questions are a good fit for Stack Overflow, see: [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so) Also please don't rely on existence of other similar questions to check whether a question is a good fit, the community might just not have gotten to them yet.

Comment: @Ali_Sh - [You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971712/what-is-the-best-way-algorithm-to-make-this-sequential-sorting-code-more-perfo) deliberately deleted your question. Which is the reason your second question was closed.

Comment: @SecurityHound That was my little experience with facing this issue, after I post the new question, I deleted that ex (it was extremely edited, but the same). But I don't think that was the reason for closing the second one. So, what to do now? I think with my follow ups on this forum and there, the post will not revived again.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It seems to me, honestly, when a post be closed, you must not post any other comments on SO or meta posts and … ([I agree with this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)), because it worsens the situation; normally it will cause others to evaluate the post by a scrutinizing look, with a negative look behind (to find probable closers’ point of views), so other potentially problems that were hidden will be flourished for others and make them agree with the closure.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It must be said that, my words are general and for all readers and **I do not intend to disrespect anyone at all**, here. Apologize for any unwanted inconvenience, because English is not my main language (Writing these comments are taking a while to avoid any unwanted upsetting).
Referring to other posts will make others become sensitive to them (it is obvious from downvotes on my post, even after closure), and I am sure that, with your experiences on SO, you know what I am talking about.

Comment: IMO, closers must be less strict and be **a little** flexible due to the internationality of this forum. Some sentences may not be written in good scheme because the author is not native in English, which can be mentioned in comments or … for the author to find the exact problem in his/her post to edit. I think my post was answerable if we don’t see it as an official contract. I agree and believe that questions must proceed in a certain framework, but must not be evaluated as the contract that we need to hire a lawyer to check the sentences.

Comment: Surely, most of the posts of the forum are not 100% based on the expected rules, and a tolerance will be considered for evaluations. How much my post was bad to be closed? Very much? IDK and I don’t think so? Do I have to pay for the uncertainty of the *You can edit the question or post a new one*, that cause my post be closed again, if *Security Hound* be right for the closure reason?

Comment: _"closers must be less strict and be a little flexible due to the internationality of this forum"_ Note that the question was not closed due to grammatical mistakes or any of the sort. Questions are not meant to be voted based directly on the author's reading and writing skills either. We also are not fond of deliberately making exceptions to curation. They just make things even harder to curate, precisely because people point at such questions and say "then why isn't that one closed??".

Comment: Calling this place a forum is misguided too. There are plenty of venues which are open to broader discussion about a problem, but this one isn't.

Comment: *You can edit the question **or post a new one.*** is, and pretty much always has been, horrible advice that gets new users banned. Can we PLEASE change that message? Pretty please with wombats on top?

Comment: @user4581301 asking nicely has never done anything. Try an angry tweet.

Comment: I don’t know why SO didn’t consider another sentence instead *post a new one* so far, or why didn’t put a hidden window for communicating between closers and the author. Surely, when a closer have time for reading a post, which will take at least 1 minute, highlighting (by selecting) suspected sentences during reading will not waste their time much than 2-5 seconds if a platform be provided for that.

Comment: (a hidden small window appear just after the closure to see the reasons, just can be seen by the author and for calling the closers to return for reverting their votes if satisfied), I know people are not funded for these reviews, but it can be reasonable and very helpful for authors to avoid knocking all doors to find the problem, which may be much more broader than the closing reasons for that post. It is just a raw suggestion.

Comment: Why not code_review be just a tag, because many professional are active just on SO (e.g., user:12939557, for Numba) and the question could be answerable (not much work) by them, and closers (reviewers) just score that to move it to CR automatically after a time (e.g., a week); By this, the authors may get better answers and more probable professionals will contribute in that. Besides, differences in opinions will not be arised for being on-topic or off-topic, open-ended or not, … , for performance tag.

Comment: @Gimby Well then. As I am not a user of Twitter, I shall bring it up with the Prime Minister.

Answer (score 17):

Because your question basically boils down to this

> As I guess the chosen algorithm will affect the performance, significantly, for this code, I am seeking for the fastest intelligent algorithm

This needs a lot more focus to be answerable. On top of that, we generally don't allow open-ended discussion of what algorithms to use. Especially

> The performance is the main objective.

We won't know how this works with your setup. Performance is quite subjective, unfortunately. And answers are likely to be of the opinion variety.

If you can come back with a section of code that appears to be under-performing (with some stats and settings to try and replicate the problem), it might be answerable.

Comment: I added the updated question into this issue, the link was attached incorrectly, I added it correctly now. please see that. In the new question, I have removed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977526/what-is-the-best-way-algorithm-to-get-the-best-performance-of-this-code

Comment: I have written *The performance is the main objective.* to say that *more precision* is not the first priority. the first is performance with considering the specified limits i.e. ranges and float type and … .

Comment: before anything else, I appreciate for you participation for help. Another matter is that I have mentioned the expected methods (*with NumPy or Numba*) for use in my new post. And also mentioned that this code will be called many times, which will be take more than12 hours based on the problem sizes (I did not mentioned how long it could take).

Comment: "I have written The performance is the main objective. to say that more precision is not the first priority." That needs to be quantified. Otherwise I can write code that returns an array of the appropriate shape filled with zeros, and consider the task complete.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In the post I have mentioned `float64` for dtype is enough, by more precise I mean like `float128` but if it doesn’t affect, adversely, the performance a lot. So, I said/meant performance with `float64` is the main concern and competition will be based on that. I wrote a code that needs to be improved, so just using `np.zeros` instead `np.empty` or … in the code to improve it even a little, will be accepted if not any more performant answer be written (I’ve removed *The performance is the main objective.* based on this answer).

Comment: I did not catch why it was *open-ended discussion*, I’ve wrote that after explanations about `float64` or `float128`, perhaps badly written? In the other hand, I didn't have any idea how much it could speed up. For example, if the code is consuming 12 hours now (*11 hours* is benched for the example), speeding up the code as much as possible is expected, but if I write expected time e.g., below 1 hours in the post (which is good enough), answerers will not put their answer if they think cannot reach it (although their code will be much performant but not gaining that, like 2 hours) (cont,)

Comment: even can be better than mine and acceptable (*and I need that*). I think an answer there, even with `np.zeros` instead `np.empty` if get better result, led to start the competition and encourage others to participate to beat that answer, if the goal of people here be to help and not to punish askers for any deficiency in his/her question, as I believe it is. if not, I must accept that. Please let me know how to request for such performance questions to get the best possible answer to avoid others blaming my question.

Comment: As my question needs Numba, Code_Review is not a good choice, because it has, so far, less than 30 answers with this tag, many not good enough IMO, and many Numba related professionals are not active there (just active on SO), so  SO is much more preferable than CR. Another thing is that my question is just a small part of my main code, short enough (*section of code that appears to be under-performing*), IMO it fits the SO. I’ve added my system setup to show what is intended, too. My code was around `np.argsort` so it was not a general question, and it needs to well-handle that. Closed again.