# How broad should questions about approximate performance of library functions be?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297945/approximate-performance-of-malloc-free), which was closed as too broad. It is about the approximate performance of a library function that is commonly used in a great many environments.

Someone further commented that the question is off-topic, but I believe it is not. I went through the guidelines of what's on topic and could not really pinpoint anything that makes this question off-topic. A linked, similar question received useful answers.

Assuming that the question is on-topic, is it too broad? I initially asked a more generic version that allows various environments to be included and/or compared in an answer. I believe this makes sense, as it would give the reader a feeling about when to consider the performance impact on a cellphone rather to a dedicated server box, etc.

However, as per the suggestions in the comments, I later narrowed it down to just one architecture. While I find this a tad unfortunate, the question should still be useful.

I'm wondering if this kind of question is useful when asked for a rather specific environment. Is it better, or worse, to address a broader range of environments? [This thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290779/is-asking-about-the-performance-of-a-library-a-valid-so-question) seems to suggest that, if an environment is specified, performance questions are on-topic. I'm unsure if this is merely allowed, or necessary.

My personal goal for my questions is to make them "as broad as possible yet as narrow as required", i.e. narrow enough to be answerable, but as long as this is given, staying generic so they apply to more use cases. However, unlike in the early days of SO, my impression in recent years is that this is poorly received and should be avoided.

---

What I want:

[image]

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is actually asking for other than running the benchmark on any arbitrary system. Perhaps you can clarify how an answer that is more than just a table could look like?

Comment: The only question I see is you asking people to run the benchmark and report back their results, even though you protest in the comments that you're not asking that. So, be specific: what are you asking?

Comment: Unless someone has access to a bunch of x64 machines, there isn't a definitive answer to your performance question. It now reads more like an invitation for others to do work and post their stats so you can tally them. That is not a good fit for a Q/A. Maybe it is salvageable if you turn it into *I need  this code to do 10^7 malloc but on my hardware I get only 10^5. What are my options to improve mallc/free OPS* because that seems to be an  answerable question.

Comment: You do understand that questions about topics that are within scope, which are too broad, can still be closed for being too broad?  Furthermore, a question can be useful, but still be out scope.

Comment: It is confusing indeed. I added the benchmark code after the comments that closed the question asked for it. I do not want anyone to run this on their machines. I just want some source that says what ballpark numbers I can expect. Is it nanoseconds? or rather milliseconds? - That kind of thing. There are differences between machines, but they are small enough to not matter (like in the picture!). I've tried to follow all advise but I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: @rene Well, the answer boils down to, do not use malloc/free so often. But that's not what I'm after. I just want to know when I should begin to think about this at all. When the program does 1000 mallocs per second? Or when it does a million? That's answerable. But I failed to convey this idea.

Comment: Pretty much always relevant for performance questions: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't asking for an opinion.  There isn't a canonical answer to "how long does malloc take", for a host of reasons, it varies depending on OS, implementation, system speed, if you include first write times, what else is going on.  Further, you'd need an answer from 20 years ago or so to scale properly in that chart, since these sort of things do change over time.

Comment: @AnonCoward The reason is that I'm merely asking for a magnitude. How long does hard disk seek take? Answer: a couple ms. Does not matter which disk, it's all similar. Do I need to worry about my data being in L2 or L3 cache when I then write them to disk? Answer: no! It's several magnitudes apart! That's the big picture. I want that for malloc.

Comment: But what if one malloc takes 10 seconds, should you worry about that one even if it shows 1ms in your chart?  What good is the chart when it makes dozens of assumptions about every element on it?  You should worry about the elements taking a long time for your scenario, not the general case.  And there's no reason to think malloc isn't something that can appear in multiple "categories" on that chart, depending on how it's used, I know of no performance guarantees for it, and certainly I have plenty of real world experience of it varying wildly.

Comment: @AnonCoward Sorry, I do not quite understand what you're getting at. I'm looking for a magnitude in the general case, and I believe there is an answer to that. I do not worry about specific instances - those have to be profiled anyway.

Comment: "those have to be profiled "  That's exactly my point.  You need to profile.  There is no universal "general case" for malloc.  If you want to put it somewhere on that chart, feel free, but many of the options on that chart are opinionated, there isn't some canonical test case for them, just one developers opinion of how often they generally take.  Malloc is no different.

Comment: @AnonCoward I disagree here. The numbers in the picture may very well be off by factor 5 or so, but that does not matter. Their rough order is consistent. I never need to worry about data being in L2 cache when I then transmit them over the internet.  Knowing this helps me focus on the areas where actual bottlenecks might be present. If I did not know this, I would needlessly profile and work on the C code for days without results.

Comment: The question pretty much just makes me wonder a lot of things. You are essentially trying to predict the future so you can pre-optimise. You must be asking that because you have a concern, right? I am missing that concern in the question, it is posed as a pure curiosity question like this. I assume that if memory allocations are going to be a problem, you are going to be writing your code different. Different how? And why not just write the code that way in any case?

Comment: @Gimby That's one way to put it, yes. Different how: There are several things that can be done, but I don't want to go into that, especially not on MSO. But these things, like any optimizations, take time, and sometimes require major architectural changes, so if it can be avoided it should be.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it should be possible to ask such question, in particular looking for performance guarantees for functions from a library - such questions may have concrete answers if the library/standard indeed provides some guarantees.

For the question you've asked I don't believe even asking "what are performance guarantees for malloc/free" alone would be ok as to my knowledge (not yet checked carefully) there are no requirements for memory allocation methods in C to behave in any particular way and hence no way to generically answer "how all runtimes should behave". I.e. I believe it is even fine to have no-op free and simply allocate memory as needed (similar to how GC-based runtimes work, just without freeing memory at all).

Additionally the question asks for very broad range of machines to benchmark code on - while some questions about benchmarking are ok (i.e. "why my benchmark on X is slower than on Y" or "will my benchmark code cover Z on {given set of devices/runtimes}"), broadly asking for all possible benchmarks on all possible machines is too much. Note that x64 covers an insanely wide range of devices supported by multiple OS and multiple C runtimes.

In summary - I don't see how to easily narrow down the linked question to be eligible for re-opening.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!
I have a few questions. First of all, do I understand you correctly that questions should restrict themselves to a narrow range of machines?

Comment: Regarding the performance guarantees: I only ask for a magnitude (like '1000 to 10000 per second'). I know that x64 is a wide range, but I think most of them are within factor 10 or 100 at least. That would be enough for me. Maybe even this vague of an answer is impossible to give, because already the magnitude of the performance fluctuates wildly (I don't believe so, but who knows). What I do not understand is why this is not an answer to my initial question. If the answer is, "it can be literally anything between 1 and a trillion", and I have to measure it on every single machine, so be it.

Comment: @mafu I don't expect any of variation of "benchmark this code for me" would stay opened - whether you narrow it down to one device or some specific subset of devices.    Canonical "[horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)" post by Eric Lippert (linked earlier in the comments) is basically the answer for all variations of such questions. "To broad" is somewhat another way to say "it can literally be anything"  - good answer would have to go into lists of reasoning why there is no concrete answer  which mostly defeats the purpose of concrete answer.

Comment: Since it is expected that questions are *practical* it is often better to close the question to allow OP to give concrete details what exactly they expect to get as an answer. Speculating about performance is one of the favorite past-time activities of developers (along with creating logging frameworks) but the only real suggestion is "profile your app" (and you seem to be very well aware of that). All resulting in poor outcomes of general "which is faster/is it fast enough for me" questions.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed responses. I'm aware of the Horses, and in principle I agree with all you said, and I've tried to include them when I (just now) asked the question again on SO. But I also feel that my judgement is still a bit different from yours - probably because my goal is a bit unusual, and is not becoming completely clear from my writing. I hope it goes better this time.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better question would be along the lines of one of these:

- How can I roughly estimate the running times of `malloc` and `free`?
- What factors most affect the running times of `malloc` and `free`?
- In what circumstances are the running times of `malloc` and `free` significant for a program's performance?

I can't promise that those questions would be well-received, but they're less broad than asking how the running times of `malloc` and `free` compare with other operations.

Comment: The points you mention could all part of a very good and thorough answer to the Q. But I'm still missing the comparison with other operations; I need this to get a picture of the involved magnitudes in my mind. I'm also worried that such questions would be closed as "even more broad" than what I asked for (expected/average case).

Comment: @mafu If it would take answers to all three of these questions to make a good answer to your question, that proves that your question is too broad, doesn't it?

Comment: It is not an easy question with a short answer. But not all questions have to be like that. Aren't many (most?) of the most upvoted questions/answers are similar in scope?